# Google Contacts API V3 not returning title for automatic contact entries

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have an app that fetches a user's contacts from the Google Contacts V3 API after the user authenticates via OAuth2 (the requests are made using JSON).  While my code works great in most circumstances, I have noticed that the API returns an empty title hash for contacts that get created automatically through emailing an address for the first time, which is less than ideal.

When I view "Other Contacts" under Google Contacts (where Google assigns these automatic contacts), these contacts seem to have an accurate title attribute.  Is there a way I could potentially get access to this value?  The response body doesn't seem to return this value within a contact entry.

Thanks.

Comment: As per note, "The feed may not contain all of the user's contacts, because there's a default limit on the number of results returned. For more information, see the max-results query parameter in [Retrieving contacts using query parameters](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters)". It could be helpful that you specify a criteria in requesting contacts such "as requesting contacts created or updated in a given date range, or published by a particular author".

Comment: Thank you MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0.  I probably should have clarified this, but in my request I'm passing the "v", "alt", "orderby", "max-results", "updated-min", "start-index", "showdeleted", and "requirealldeleted" parameters.  I do receive a response containing the entries in question, but the attribute that returns the title/name is blank.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "title". Like "Dr." or "Mrs.", or something else?

Comment: Hi Eric, when I say "title", I'm basically referring to the name of the hash in the API response that stores the contact's first name and last name.  Thanks.